# Symbolic definite integral expression does not yield the same result as numerical evaluation

Tags: sympy

I resolved the definite integral of an expression using sympy in order to get the symbolic expression of the integral. However, when I use the yielded expression in a function, I do not get the same result as given by the numerical evaluation of the integral:

```
>> from sympy import *
>> x, y, a, b, c, d, k = symbols ('x y a b c d k', positive=True)
>> res = integrate(exp(-k*abs(x-y)), (x, a, b), (y, c, d))

>> res
(-exp(a*k) + exp(b*k))*exp(-b*k)*exp(-k*(a - d))/k**2 - (-exp(a*k) + exp(b*k))*exp(-b*k)*exp(-k*(a - c))/k**2

>> def integral_1(k1, a1, b1, c1, d1):
>>     return (-exp(a1*k1) + exp(b1*k1))*exp(-b1*k1)*exp(-k1*(a1 - d1))/k1**2 - (-exp(a1*k1) + exp(b1*k1))*exp(-b1*k1)*exp(-k1*(a1 - c1))/k1**2

>> integral_1(0.6, 0, 1, 0, 1)
1.0303623235681536

>> integrate(exp(-0.6*abs(x-y)), (x, 0, 1), (y, 0, 1))
0.826731311633480
```

Why do I get such difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbolic output is wrong due to a SymPy bug. Aside: the better way to demonstrate it is `res.subs({k: 0.6, a: 0, b: 1, c: 0, d: 1})` which returns 1.03..., which is clearly impossible for the integral of a function bounded by 1 on the unit square.

The problem is that SymPy (as of version 1.3) does not correctly handle `abs` in this integral. Its output `res` would be the same if you did not include `abs` at all. A simpler example:

```
>>> integrate(exp(abs(x-y)), (x, a, b))
-exp(a - y) + exp(b - y)
```

This can't be right, because the integral has to depend on how y is placed relative to a and b.

A remedy (until the bug is fixed) is to apply `rewrite(Piecewise)` to the integrand, replacing `abs` with a Piecewise function. For example, `exp(abs(x-y)).rewrite(Piecewise)` returns `exp(Piecewise((x - y, x - y >= 0), (-x + y, True)))` which integrates correctly. After

```
res = integrate(exp(-k*abs(x-y)).rewrite(Piecewise), (x, a, b), (y, c, d))
```

the result is long and ugly, but correct:

```
>>> res.subs({k: 0.6, a: 0, b: 1, c: 0, d: 1})
0.826731311633481
```

The result will be not as long and ugly if you tell SymPy that a < b, like so:

```
>>> res.subs({a < b: True})
-2*Min(d, Max(a, c))/k + 2*Min(d, Max(a, b, c))/k + (-exp(a*k) + exp(b*k))*exp(-b*k)*exp(-k*(a - Min(d, Max(a, c))))/k**2 - (-exp(a*k) + exp(b*k))*exp(-b*k)*exp(-k*(a - Min(c, d)))/k**2 - (exp(a*k) - exp(b*k))*exp(-a*k)*exp(-k*(-a + Min(d, Max(a, b, c))))/k**2 + (exp(a*k) - exp(b*k))*exp(-a*k)*exp(-k*(-a + d))/k**2 - (-k**2*exp(a*k)*exp(k*(-a + Min(d, Max(a, c)))) + k**2*exp(b*k)*exp(-k*(-a + Min(d, Max(a, c)))))*exp(-b*k)/k**4 + (-k**2*exp(a*k)*exp(k*(-a + Min(d, Max(a, b, c)))) + k**2*exp(b*k)*exp(-k*(-a + Min(d, Max(a, b, c)))))*exp(-b*k)/k**4
```

Comment: Thanks, this trick worked. At least I have the assurance that it was a bug. I trieds also to do: `res = integrate(exp(-k * sign(x - y)*(x - y)), (x, a, b), (y, c, c))` but this yielded the same error (res=1.03036232356815).